# Implementing Top Down Parser in java

Tags: java, parsing, data-structures, topdown

I have to code a top down parser in java. I know the algorithms and everything nicely to calculate FIRST and FOLLOW and parsing a string. But I dont know how to begin. So any help would be appreciated for these quesions:

1. How to give a grammar. What data structures should I use for that.
2. Are there any APIs tat can guide me towards my goal.

Comment: Look for JavaCc. It is an top down parser generator with examples. Or do you have to implement all by yourself? Give more details about the data to parse.

Comment: You can also use java cup.

Comment: Antlr creates bottom up not top down parser.

Comment: i need to input a grammar. it should prepare its FIRST and FOLLOW and a parse table. everything should be built by myself, no tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use JavaCC. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf) to get you started. The learning curve will require a couple of hours of your time but you'll be glad you did in the long run.